# Python: SSL unable to get local issuer certificate even though the cert exists

Tags: python, ssl, flask

I'm trying to use the SuiteCRM api to make a query. I have no problem doing this on my local machine (Windows 10). But I keep encountering this: `requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='****', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /service/v4_1/rest.php?login (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1076)')`

On my Amazon EC2 instance running Linux (CentOS). Despite the fact that I have `certifi` installed and I can see `cacert.pem` in the proper folder. I confirmed this by running:

```
import certifi
certifi.where()
```

Which gave me '/var/www/html/flask_api/flask_env/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/certifi/cacert.pem'

But the problem persists, I tried putting

```
os.environ['REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE'] = os.path.join(
    '/etc/ssl/certs/',
    'ca-bundle.crt')
```

At the top of my file as well, I was reading requests uses `REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE` but to no avail. I just feel `requests` isn't actually locating the certificate. I'm using Apache's virtual host, not sure that matters. The error is occurring at the API

edit: Apache Vritual Host config

```
<VirtualHost *:1024>
     WSGIDaemonProcess flask_api python-path=/var/www/html/flask_api:/var/www/html/flask_api/flask_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages
     # Add machine's IP address (use ifconfig command)
     ServerName ****
     # DocumentRoot /home/ec2-user/flask_api/
     # Give an alias to to start your website url with
     WSGIScriptAlias /api /var/www/html/flask_api/api.wsgi
     <Directory /var/www/html/flask_api>
            WSGIProcessGroup flask_api
            WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
                # set permissions as per apache2.conf file
            Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
     </Directory>
     LogLevel warn
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: It might be a setup problem of the _unknown_ server. Missing intermediate certificates are a common problem which cause such an error. Check the server with [SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html) and look for *chain issues* or other problems.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Thank you I will do that

Comment: What are you referring when you say "unknown server"?

Comment: Simply that you don't provide any information about the server. Nothing its known about the setup, nothing is known about the server name to check how it behaves ... - so it is only possible to widely guess what might be the problem but not to actually be sure about the cause.

Comment: I updated my question with my apache server configuration

Comment: Your problem is SSL related. Only there is nothing SSL related in the part of the Apache config you show. So these information do not help. Have you already checked SSLLabs?

Comment: I tested the code again in a separate script that's not served via apache. Still no luck. I tried SSL Labs. It shows there are two certificates. Both of them have an option to download the cert. I've already tried downloading the first one and putting it in `cacert.pem` to no avail.

Comment: I fixed the problem, I was right about the cert being missing. But downloading `certifi` wasn't enough. I ended taking the certs I had from my local machine and pasting them into the `cacert.pem` file under the `certifi` directory on my remote server.